# Why this program does not give ambiguity error

Tags: java, this

I have a java program where a paramaterized constructor is used with the parameters names same as that of instance variables.
In such case we need to use this keyword. But when I do not use this keyword it does not gives any error instead it initializes instance variables with default values.

```
class Demo{
    int a;
    Demo(int a)
    {
       a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Demo d = new Demo(5);
    }
}
```

But when this program is executed the value of a becomes 0. How?

Comment: Java will initialised class members to known default values, in this case `int` is defaulted to `0`, since you never actually change it, the value remains the same (`0`)

Comment: Actually, with appropriate warnings enabled, you may see one that tells you parameter assignment is a bad thing.

Answer (score 7):

There's no ambiguity - in `a = a;`, *both* `a`'s unambiguously refer to the parameter, because that is the "innermost" variable called `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is perfectly valid to assign the same value to same variable. So `a = a` is perfectly valid code.

But what you want to achieve is to assign value of `a` (method variable) to `this.a` (instance variable). So you need to use `this` keyword to refer to instance variable.

```
Demo(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

If you do not want to use `this` keyword then you need to rename method variable like

```
Demo(int b) {
    a = b; // a will refer to instance variable in this case.
}
```

---

> my question was how a's value become zero.

Refer : [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Primitive datatype variable are initialized with default value. And for `int` **0** is default value.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the local variable `a` in your code instead assigning it's value to the class variable. And the class variable is initialised with zero.

Do

```
 Demo(int a) {
   this.a = a;
 }
```

Comment: i know that we need to use this keyword. But my question was how a's value become zero.